# I have 2 functions in the same class, and I want to modify the size of a vector in one function, and have this new size in the other function?

Tags: c++, function, class, vector, object-oriented-analysis

I have 2 functions in the same class, and I want to modify the size of a vector in one function, and have this new size in the other function?

I have a

```
class A 
{
 void add_vector (int val){
         value.push_back(val); 
         value.push_back(val); 
        cout << value.size() << endl; 

void check_size(){
 cout << value.size() << endl; 
}


private: 
vector<int>value;
```

i know the syntax here isnt perfect, i have done everything better in my real code, but my problem is in the class check size, my value table becomes size 0 though i have changed it in add_vector function

How do i apply the same vector size to the check_value size

Comment: You seem to be missing one or more closing braces.  Post your exact code.  In C++, a single character could have a large impact on the operation of your code.

Comment: I set this up as a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4c076cf3fe6d764) and it works fine.  Post your actual code as a demo to get more help and so that we can see that a problem actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are aware but there is a syntax error surrounding that you are not closing the first function `void add_vector (int val)`

Having closed the function and tested the code it works.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class foo{
private: 
    std::vector<int>value;
public:
    void add_vector(int val){
        value.push_back(val);
        value.push_back(val);
        std::cout << value.size() << std::endl;
    }

    void check_size(){
        std::cout << value.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Hope that this helps.